# Webview app works first time app is installed but after that shows only blank white screen

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

When the app is installed for first time, everything works fine, but after closing the app and opening again, there is only white screen. The website does not load.

MainActivity.java file

```
package app.freeairdrop.io;
import ....

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private WebView webView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setMax(100);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    // webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);        
    mySwipeRefreshLayout = 
    (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);


    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    webView.reload();
                    mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
    );



private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if (uri.getHost() != null && (url.startsWith("https://freeairdrop.io/") || url.startsWith("https://www.freeairdrop.io/"))) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
    }
}


private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    else {
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
// This method is used to detect back button
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack()) {
        this.webView.goBack();
        return;
    }

    else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(appLinkData));

    } else if (getIntent().getExtras() == null){
        webView.loadUrl("https://freeairdrop.io/");

    }else {
        webView.loadUrl("https://freeairdrop.io/");
    }
    super.onStart();


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf(appLinkData));

    } else if (getIntent().getExtras() == null){
        webView.loadUrl("https://freeairdrop.io/");

    }else {
        webView.loadUrl("https://freeairdrop.io/");
    }
    super.onResume();
 }

}
```

AndroidMamifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="app.freeairdrop.io">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:appCategory="productivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name="app.freeairdrop.io.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="freeairdrop.io" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Whenever I go to the app using website link , using deeplink it works everytime, i.e if someone gets a link to my website on whatsapp and he clicks on it and open that link using my app, it is opening perfectly. Just like we can open youtube app if we gets video link on whatsapp.

Comment: put a log for url and check what you are getting each time.

Comment: @HariNJha sorry I didn't understand

Comment: Put a log for URI in onStart and shouldOverrideUrlLoading to see what is passing to load in webview. Second thing, why you calling onStart and onResume both. Know the Activity life cycle properly and then implement.

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent().getExtras()` might not be null but having a non URL value. Go an extra step to check the value before passing it to webview using [URLUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/URLUtil)

Modify block `onResume` and `onStart`

```
String gotoUrl = String.valueOf(appLinkData);

if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(gotoUrl))
     webView.loadUrl(gotoUrl);
  else webView.loadUrl("https://freeairdrop.io/");
```

Comment: It does not work. Can you please provide the full modifies onStart method ?

Answer (score 0):

**May This [Repo](https://github.com/SabithPkcMnr/WebViewMaster) Help You Check it to see if**